# Casttype efficiency

Tags: php, casting

It's been on my mind for a number of days, i sometimes find myself having to use the *Type Juggling* method which is available to PHP: [Type Juggling Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

and have headed into the subject of efficiency/Correct methods.. To showcase a similar scenario which is on my mind would be:

```
/*
    The benchmark test: 
        Expected Output: string
            Actual Output: string 
*/
$Percentile = "20%";
echo gettype($Percentile); 
?>
<br><br>
Force Casting to an Integer: 
<br><br>
<?php
    /*
        Remove the %age from the string before force re-cast
            Expected Output: integer 
            Actual Output: integer 
                Test Passed 
    */
    unset($Percentile); // Just to reduce any cached validations 
    $Percentile = "20%";
    $Percentile = (int)$Percentile;
    echo $Percentile."\r\n";
    echo gettype($Percentile);
?>
<br><br>
Str Replace to remove the '%' and cast to integer
<br><br>
<?php 
    /*
        Remove the %age from the string before force re-cast
            Expected Output: integer 
            Actual Output: integer 
                Test Passed 
    */
    unset($Percentile);
    $Percentile = "20%";
    $Percentile_New = str_replace("%","",$Percentile);
    echo $Percentile_New."\r\n"; // 
    echo gettype((int)$Percentile_New);
?>
```

After reading all the tests pass with expected results, but trying to force;

```
$Percentile = 20%;
```

which returns the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

So eitherway, creating percentages will be created using a string cast representation, but this isn't the main purpose of the question..

The overall question is which way is more efficient?

*Method 1:*

Force cast type to integer with not removing the %age

*Method 2:*

use `str_replace` then force cast type to integer after removing the %age

Efficiency being less room for incorrect data cast types (if such a problem may occur)

Comment: `$Percentile = 0.2` should definitely be the most efficient method of assigning the value.

Comment: You seem to be using a strange definition of "efficient". This usually refers to coade that runs faster or uses less memory.

Comment: @Barmar True, lets substitute efficiency for reliability

Comment: You should probably not depend on automatic conversions of random formats. If you know a priori that the percentage string ends with `%`, use `substr` to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that example, it clearly is more efficient NOT doing any string operations, but directly using the type cast. The result for the given string is the same.